# how to extract data frame elements that has a specified word in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `twts` consisting of movie tweets that was retrieved from twitter . I want to extract specified elements of the data frame that has the word like "music" and store them in another data frame object. I thought of using for loops and parsing every sentence word by word. So is there any other efficient ways or in-buid functions to do the desired action.?

input : twt (initial data.frame)

```
[1] "Music is so nice"
[2] "the movie rocked"
[3] "the hero is the best"
[4] "theme music at its peak"
```

output : music (new data.frame)

```
[1] "Music is so nice"
[2] "theme music at its peak"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: `?grep` should help you - you specifically want the `grepl` variant

Answer (score -1):

`> twt <- c("Music is so nice", "the movie rocked", "the hero is the best", "theme music at its peak")`

`> twt[grep("music", twt, ignore.case = TRUE)]
[1] "Music is so nice"     "theme music at its peak"`